# Systick interruption doesn't trigger when handling another interrupt

Tags: c, arm, stm32, interrupts, cortex-m

I am experimenting with the `STM32f4` discovery and i tried to use a delay (based on `SYSTICK`) in an `EXTI_IRQ` handler but i figured out that while the `EXTI` handler is triggered the the `systick` handler doesn't trigger , here's my code :

```
extern volatile int del ;
void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void) {

  if (EXTI_GetITStatus(EXTI_Line0) != RESET ) {
        /* Do your stuff when PD0 is changed */
         del=1000 ;
         while(del)
       {
       //do something 
       }

       /* Clear interrupt flag */
        EXTI_ClearITPendingBit(EXTI_Line0);
    }
  }
```

And the systick handler :

```
void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
  if (del--)
 ;
}
```

So how can i solve this problem .

Comment: on most CPUs, interrupts have an order of precedence.  A higher precedence interrupt will mask a lower precedence interrupt while the higher precedence interrupt is being handled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can, if your processor allows it (it should, since I believe all of that series are Cortex M4 based), set the Systick Interrupt to a higher priority than the other interrupts and then find out if you can make your compiler/processor not turn off interrupts globally while processing an interrupt.

That is, if you want to have delays in your interrupts.

Hint: You shouldn't want that.

Interrupts are meant to run efficiently and quickly to handle important events that are critical. If something needs a delay beyond a couple of `ASM("__volatile__ NOP\n NOP\n NOP\n")`'s, it's probably not something you want in your interrupt.

If you have a "heavy task" that gets triggered by an interrupt it's much neater to write:

```
uint32_t taskFlags;  // semafore register, can also be any other data type that fits your flags (1ul --> uint32_t or larger!)
#define HANDLE_MY_INTERRUPT_STUFF    (1ul<<0) // Define a flag for interrupt things.

void main(void) {
    while(1) {
        if(taskFlags & HANDLE_MY_INTERRUPT_STUFF) { // Check the flag
            // Do your interrupt stuff
            // Allowed to have many delays and other weird stuff
            
            taskFlags &= ~HANDLE_MY_INTERRUPT_STUFF; // Clear the flag.
        }
    }
}

InterruptHandler(void) {
    taskFlags |= HANDLE_MY_INTERRUPT_STUFF;  // set the flag
}
```

And now suddenly all that heavy processing gets done in the main loop, where it can be interrupted and all and won't harm any other time-critical things. But only triggered by the interrupt source, through the flags.

Although through the flags you will of course risk a slight variable delay in execution, it's always a balancing act.

#### Late addition:

Between processor types the delay will usually be between 4 and 40 clock cycles + average other interrupt code execution, so at a couple MHz using a 10ms delay will usually already marginalise that delay and its variation.)

Comment: but what if it's the case when you need to denounce a button ( the case of interruption triggered with push button ) with a delay i know i can make delay with a for loop but it's a bad solution .

Comment: @starter see the second part. Anything you do inside the interrupt can be done in the main with a flag. It's _that_ simple.

Comment: thank you that was helpful , i was over complicating life .

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest solution to do:

```
extern __IO uint32_t TimmingDelay;

void Delay(__IO uint32_t time)
{
  TimmingDelay = time;
  while(TimmingDelay != 0);
}
```

This is in stm32f4xx_it.c:

```
void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
  if(TimmingDelay != 0)
  {
    TimmingDelay --;
   }
  }
```

In main don't forget to add this line:

```
  SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock/1000000);
```

and then use Delay("AddDelayHere"); and spam all over your code.

Comment: This isn't guaranteed to solve the interrupt conflict